# Meaning of "run around doing something"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does *run around doing something* mean?

For example:

> I can't see any reason to run around deleting the recovery partition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run around doing something is to do it recklessly or haphazardly, or to flit about while doing it. *Go around* is related:

> You can't just go around telling everybody what to do.

And both are often used in reference to doing something without paying attention or considering the consequences:

> I can't see any reason to be so reckless as to delete the recovery partition.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a metaphor for wasting energy doing something.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of *run around (with)* is the same of *run with*: to proceed (with).

> I can't see any reason to proceed deleting the recovery partition.

Comment: No, it's more than that. I think Joel Spolsky has the right answer.